# Проверить список страниц на необходимое мне содержимое

Tags: javascript, php

Есть список страниц, нужно проверить каждую страницу на наличие содержимого, если есть страница, оставить ее в списке, если нет - удалить

Скрипт автоматизировано должен работать (я не буду проходиться по каждой ссылке, их 1000) проверял каждый элемент из массива (страницу) на необходимый мне один и тот же div, если этот див есть на странице, то оставлять страницу в массиве, если нет удалять из массива

Comment: if (есть) { оставить страницу } else { удалить страницу } :)

Comment: ну это понятно, а как сделать, чтобы скрипт автоматизировано (я не буду проходиться по каждой ссылке, их 1000) проверял каждый элемент из массива (страницу) на необходимый мне один и тот же div, если этот див есть на странице, то оставлять страницу в массиве, если нет удалять из массива

Answer (score 0):

[headless-chromium](https://github.com/chrome-php/headless-chromium-php) в помощь

```
for($i=0; $i<count($urls); $i++) {
    $page = $browser->createPage($urls[$i]);
    if ($page->evaluate('document.querySelector("selector") === null') {
        unset($urls[$i]);
    }
}
```

как-то так

Comment: а можете сказать как подключить синтаксис headless-chromium-php к самому headless-chromium и запускать через node.js?